# Can you add an object that is available in the request context only?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Spring (java) and in .NET also, you can add an object in request scope?

i.e. a user makes a request, you perform some look in a filter or base controller, and then you can add this object into the request object for this current request only

Now in your Action you can check if the key exists and use this object in your action method.

Comment: you cannot add property to object in runtime, but you can use HashMap and put your object in it

Comment: What version of Play are you using, 1 or 2?

Comment: 2.2.x or even latest.

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2 `Request`s are immutable so you would generally wrap them and pass them around rather than modifying them.

You'd usually use something called [*action composition*](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) to do what you want. Action composition lets you write common code for actions so that you can pre-process a requests and maybe pass the action some data from the request.

Check out the `Authenticated` example in the [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) which provides the action with an `AuthenticatedRequest` object. The `AuthenticatedRequest` object wraps the existing `Request` (rather than modifying it) and adds an additional `username` value.

Comment: Ok so this would have to be done at the action level, not the controller level right?

Comment: Each Action would be built using composition, but you could define your composition rules in one place, e.g. in an controller trait.

Answer (score 0):

As Rich said, you can use Action Composition and, if you want to put more information in Request context, you can use Http.current().args.put("key","value").